# Полоса чи шпальта?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Часто можна почути: ["На першій полосі сьогоднішньої газети..."](http://uapress.info/uk/news/show/45180), хоча більшість результатів за словом *полоса* в гуглпошуку належить російським ресурсам. Та СУМ таки містить слово полоса:

> ПОЛОСА́, и, жін. Набрана або видрукувана сторінка книги, журналу, газети. На редакційній мові газетну сторінку називають полосою (Наука і життя, 5, 1962, 6); — Я всю увагу звернув на великого розміру політичні статті, коли вичитував полоси (Павло Автомонов, Коли розлучаються двоє, 1959, 692).

Також присутнє більш українське, на мою думку, слово шпальта(має трохи ширше значення, ніж полоса):

> ШПА́ЛЬТА, и, жін.
>   1. Ряд коротких рядків у газеті, журналі і т. ін., розташованих один під одним так, що вони становлять вертикальну смугу на сторінці. Сей том розійшовся досить швидко і зробився тепер майже бібліографічною рідкістю, хоча видання, невважаючи на старанність, вийшло непоказне (дешевенький папір, дрібний друк у дві шпальти, куценька передмова) (Іван Франко, XVI, 1955, 310);
>   //  рідко. Гранка. На столі перед професором лежала купа друкарських гранок-шпальт: професор готував для перевидання скорочений курс своєї наукової праці (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 82); 
>   //  Сторінка газети, журналу і т. ін. О першій приходять газети з Москви. Листоношу дружина в дверях зустріла. Зі шпальти на мене дивитесь ви, Семеро негрів Мартінсвілла (Леонід Первомайський, II, 1958, 19);
>   //  Ряд цифр, слів, послідовно написаних одне під одним; стовпчик. Мартіан.. виносить.. календар — мармуровий кубик з написаним на ньому календарним текстом у три стовпці на кожному боці. [Люцілла (переглянувши одну шпальту):] Так, правда, день Венери.., Слава богу! (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 306). 
>    На шпальтах газет (газетних, журналів і т. ін.) — в газетах, журналах і т. ін. Харків, Харків, на пера багнети ми змінили в ті сонячні дні, щоб лунали на шпальтах газетних молоді переможців пісні (Володимир Сосюра, I, 1957, 236);

То чи правильно використовувати *полоса газети*, чи не є це русизмом?

Comment: Зазначу, що _шпальта_ німецьке слово і вже може бути також полонізмом чи таки ґерманізмом.

Answer (score 1):

Ви справді праві і краще не вживати "полоса газети", а казати "[шпальта газети](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/ru/%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0)". Приклад: "Жодний фотограф не зробить репортаж про наш героїзм, жодний журналіст не славитиме нас на першій шпальті газети". І Гугл-перекладач також "на первых полосах" перекладає як "на перших шпальтах"